# MySQL - Subquery Condition

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, conditional-statements

I have 2 tables:

`tbl_projects`
`tbl_projects_tasks`

It's a simple tasks management interface.  And the Tasks are assigned to Projects.
I also have a column, inside the Tasks Table, called `percentage`, which is an integer field.  I do keep it from `0` - `100`, naturally for percentage reasons.

Also, inside the Projects table I have another column called: `projectpercentagedone`

This column Averages all Tasks related to an Project.

Here's the query that does the averaging (using a single projectid in my example):

```
UPDATE `tbl_projects` SET
`totaltasks` = (SELECT COUNT(taskid) AS T1 FROM `tbl_projects_tasks` WHERE projectid = 10),
`projectpercentagedone` = (SELECT AVG(percentage) AS T2 FROM `tbl_projects_tasks` WHERE projectid = 10) 
WHERE projectid = 10 
LIMIT 1
```

I want to go a step further, for more advanced settings reasons.

If the total AVG is 100%, I'd like to update the `projectvisible` of `tbl_projects` from `1` to `0`.

Of course, I could do 2 queries in secession. But I'm sure a single query is way more cool.
This type of conditional statement is a little above my experience.  I'm looking for a little help in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply join `tbl_projects` into a subquery which do some calculations on `tbl_projects_tasks`.

```
UPDATE  tbl_projects a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  projectid, 
                    COUNT(taskID) totalCount,
                    AVG(percentage) avgPercent
            FROM    tbl_projects_tasks
            GROUP   BY projectid
        ) b ON  a.projectid = b.projectid
SET     a.totaltasks = b.totalCount,
        a.projectpercentagedone = b.avgPercent,
        a.projectvisible = IF(b.avgPercent = 100, 0, 1)
WHERE   a.projectid = 10
```

Comment: I see where you are going with this.  Your query gets me a sql syntax error, but I'm adjusting it.....

Comment: what is the exact error that was generated so I can fix the query.

Comment: `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'COUNT(taskid) totalCount, AVG(percent) avgPercent ' at line 5`

I've been changing it up, just to be sure I didn't mistype anything. Sorry for the delays

Comment: did you forget to add comma? can i show the query you have executed?

Comment: `UPDATE tbl_projects p 
    INNER JOIN 
        (
        SELECT projectid
                COUNT(taskid) totalCount,
                AVG(taskcompletion) avgPercent 
        FROM tbl_projects_tasks 
        GROUP BY projectid
        ) b ON p.projectid = b.projectid 
SET p.projecttasksnum = b.totalCount,
    p.projectpercentagedone = b.avgPercent,
    p.projectonoff = IF(b.avgPercent = 100, 0, 1) 
WHERE p.projectid = 30 LIMIT 1`

Comment: I made a few alterations (db changes since yesterday), but I believe it's how you displayed it.
See anything amiss?

Comment: yes, a comma between projectID and COUNT(). `UPDATE tbl_projects p INNER JOIN ( SELECT projectid, COUNT(taskid) totalCount,...`

Comment: Ah, you were right!  I was focused on the Wrong place of the comma.